# Google Cloud Storage - Downloading a file using CURL request

Tags: curl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, blob, storage

I am trying to download a file from the cloud storage bucket using the curl request as explained here - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#download-object-json

In the above docs, In step1, I see the access token is getting generated from the [Oauth 2.0 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). However, I want to programmatically generate the token and send the CURL request. \

Is there any way to get the access token through any script? Probably from another CURL request using the service account?

Answer (score 5):

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

[Bash OAuth 2.0 JWT script for Server to google Server Applications](https://superuser.com/questions/606953/bash-oauth-2-0-jwt-script-for-server-to-google-server-applications)

[Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects)

```
#1. Create a service account with storage permissions to download the objects and download the p12 key file


#2. Convert p12 key to pem
PRIVATE_KEY=privateKey.pem
openssl pkcs12 -in privatekey.p12 -nodes -nocerts --passin pass:notasecret > $PRIVATE_KEY


#3. Create an object and uploaded to storage
cat file
#This is a testing file
gsutil cp file gs://your-bucket/


#4.Create a JSON Web Token (JWT, pronounced, "jot") which includes a header, a claim set, and a signature.

ALG=RS256
TYP=JWT

JSON_HEADER=$( jq -n --arg alg "$ALG" --arg typ "$TYP"  '{alg: $alg, typ: $typ}' )
JSON_HEADER_ENCODED=`echo -n $JSON_HEADER | openssl base64 -e`

ISS=user@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
SCOPE=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
AUD=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
IAT=$(date +%s)
EXP=$(($IAT + 3600))



JSON_CLAIM=$( jq -n --arg iss "$ISS" --arg scope "$SCOPE" --arg aud "$AUD" --arg exp "$EXP" --arg iat "$IAT"  '{iss: $iss, scope: $scope, aud: $aud, exp: $exp, iat: $iat}');
JSON_CLAIM_ENCODED=`echo -n $JSON_CLAIM | openssl base64 -e`


HEAD_AND_CLAIM_TR=`echo -n "$JSON_HEADER_ENCODED.$JSON_CLAIM_ENCODED" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`
echo $HEAD_AND_CLAIM_TR

SIGNATURE_ENCODED=`echo -n "$HEAD_AND_CLAIM_TR" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign $PRIVATE_KEY | openssl base64 -e`
SIGNATURE_TR=`echo -n "$SIGNATURE_ENCODED" | tr -d '\n' | tr -d '=' | tr '/+' '_-'`
echo $SIGNATURE_TR


JWT_ASSERTION="$HEAD_AND_CLAIM_TR.$SIGNATURE_TR"
echo $JWT_ASSERTION


#5. Request an access token from the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server.
RESPONSE=`curl -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" -d \
"grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=$JWT_ASSERTION" `


#6. Handle the JSON response that the Authorization Server returns.
BEARER=`echo $RESPONSE | jq '.access_token'`


#7. Download the object from GCS
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $BEARER" \
  -o "test_file" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/your-bucket/o/file?alt=media" 
 
  
#8. Test it
cat test_file
#This is a testing file
```

Answer (score 4):

With CURL, you can use this command `gcloud auth print-access-token`. To achieve this, you need to be authenticated with your user credentials `gcloud auth login`

If you only have a service account key file (because your script don't run locally or on Google Cloud environment) you can load the credentials like this: `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=<YOUR FILE>`

Then, your CURL command looks like this

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -o "SAVE_TO_LOCATION" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o/OBJECT_NAME?alt=media"
```

*the `$()` execute a linux command and print the output*

If you want to create this access token programmatically, the Google Auth library can help you to achieve this. *Let us know your favorite language if you want code samples.*

Answer (score 1):

You can get this access token, if you are logged to Cloud SDK (gcloud) on the same machine you are running cURL command.

The process looks like this:

1. Create service account and give access
2. Generate download json account key
3. run command: `gcloud auth activate-service-account [ACCOUNT-NAME] --key-file=/path/to/service-key.json --project=[PROJECT_ID]`
4. use as "Authorization: Bearer" `$(gcloud auth print-access-token)`

Here is Google [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/programmatic-oauth-clients#service_accounts_and_gcloud) to this process.

I replicated this on my testing project and such command worked perfectly:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -o "test.jpg" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/[bucket-name]/o/original.jpg?alt=media"
```